# Import turned curve into several faces

Tags: import, faces

Background (I modeled this object on autocad, open the dwg in sketchup and saved as DAE file)

I opened the DAE file on blender and instead of a curve I'm presented with several faces in the shape of the curve - as seen in the pics.

How do I turn it into a single curve and smooth it?

I apologize if it's a basic question but I have been looking around (tutorials) but I can't seem to find an answer.

Thank you in advance

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Blender is not NURBS modeler (even though it has a basic shapes) ...
Also I'm not sure if DAE can handle this kind of data. Export is usually converted to polygons.

To smooth curvature you can

- simply use **Shade Smooth** with *Normals* set to **Auto** to keep edges sharp ...
- or with combination of **Subdivision Surface** modifier limited to Angle ...
- or create an curve oval shape and use another curve with such vertical profile to be **Bevel** of first curve

Under blender 3 it can be done also via Bevel Profile properties of the first oval shape ... [See Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/curves/properties/geometry.html)